# discrete math/ probability question

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

We have two sets of numbers: $v_1 \cdots v_N$ and $v_1' \cdots v_N'$. $v_i \geq 0 \forall i $ and $v'_i \geq 0 \forall i$

We know two things about them: $\sum v_i = \sum v_i' = 1 $  and

$\frac{v_i}{v_j}\geq \frac{v_i'}{v_j'}  \forall i < j$

Now we also have numbers $A \cdots N$ where $A > B > ... > N$.

I want to show $Av_1 + ... + N v_N \geq Av_1' + ... + Nv_n'$

Thanks!

Comment: You have tagged this under probability. Can we assume that the numbers are positive (and therefore smaller equal 1 as their sum has to be 1)?

Comment: Yes, sorry I did not make that clear